# Ajax Posting multiple Arrays to MVC 4 controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

Im having what I think is quite a strange problem and im hoping its just something iv overlooked. Im trying to pass some arrays to my mvc controller using ajax, from my console output I can see the correct values are being posted BUT it seems that just ONE of them will *not* bind correctly and I just get null **but** only if the other 2 arrays have values. If the other 2 are null then KnownTo will bing correctly.

Here is my javascript code

```
var sectors = new Array();
var offices = new Array();
var KnownTo = new Array();
```

on a click event i add to these arrays by checking some data attributes on certain elements on a page. I then do the request.

```
postData = {
            'Sector': sectors,
            'Offices': offices, 
            'KnownTo': KnownTo 
        };

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        url: 'Controller/SearchActivities',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        success: function (result) {
           console.log(result)
        },
        failure: function (result) {
           console.log(result)
        }
    });
```

After the ajax call i see the correct values posted in firebug.

I then get to the controller...

```
 [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SearchActivities(FilterPageViewModel model)
    {
           //something
    }
```

The sectors and offices are filled correctly but my KnownTo is not. Here is the FilterPageViewModel

```
public class FilterPageViewModel
{
    public int[] Sector{ get; set; }
    public int[] Offices{ get; set; }
    public int[] KnownTo{ get; set; }
}
```

Now the strange thing is, if only KnownTo has values posted to it and the other 2 are null then KnownTo gets binded **correctly**, but if there are values on either of the other arrays then KnownTo will be **null** no matter what. I hope that make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by just re naming the KnownTo array to something else. Im guessing KnownTo is a reserved word of some kind.